# how to add columns in grid dynamically in ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

i want the grid columns dynamically in ionic2 i have write following code in .html file

```
    <ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row text-center>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let name of grid;" 
                  [value]="grid">{{name.grid}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and in .ts file

```
 grid = [
 {
   grid: 'CSE',
 },
 {
   grid: 'I.T',
 }];         

   selectedGrid = this.grid[0];
```

but it is not working what should do?

Comment: You should use array variable for ngFor in template like this : grid = [ 'CSE' , 'I.T' ]

Comment: its not working for me can you give some help?

Answer (score -2):

I used this is my code, hope it helps

```
 <ion-row >
      <ion-col col-1 class="heading">
        <div> S/N</div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4 class="heading">
        <div>Description</div>
      </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-1 class="heading">
        <div>QTY</div>
      </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3 class="heading">
        <div>Unit Price (NGN)</div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3 class="heading">
        <div>Value (NGN)</div>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>


 <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-col col-1 >
        <div> {{item.id}} </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4 >
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
      </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-1 class="qty" >
        <div>{{item.qty}}</div>
      </ion-col>
     <ion-col col-3  class="value">
        <div>{{item.unit_price}}</div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3   class="value">
        <div>{{item.amount}}</div>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: In general, code only answers are not constructive. You should also explain how it solves OPs problem.